# Passing list arguments to functions

Tags: python, list, function

I'm using a function from scipy to construct block-diagonal matrices, which takes as an argument several matrices and returns the desired result, i.e.,

```
block_diag(A,B,C)
```

returns the associated block-diagonal form. My code naturally computes these matrices and returns them in a list in the following format and can be converted to a block diagonal matrix as follows:

```
ops = [A, B, C]
block_diag(ops[0],ops[1],ops[2])
```

Unfortunately the form

```
block_diag(ops)
```

throws an error. The problem is that I want this to work for an arbitrary number of operators, so I need a way to call the block diagonal function which doesn't require me to enumerate terms of the form op[j]. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: That would just be `block_diag(*ops)` to turn your list elements into individual parameters.

Comment: This is amazing, thanks